# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 Flutter Bloc Stream

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am working with flutter bloc stream to get data from firestore. But bloc is giving a null list and when I do hot reload it shows me the complete products. My problem is why it is showing the products when the app is build? After hot reload it is showing products perfectly

Here is my code

**BlocBuilder**

```
BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is ProductLoading) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: primaryColor,
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (state is ProductLoaded) {
                  print(state.products);
                  return Container(
                    height: screenSize.height * .31,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        primary: false,
                        itemCount: 4,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return productCard(
                            product: state.products[index],
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },

        ),
```

**Product Bloc.Dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:burgerhub/constants/utils.dart';
import 'package:burgerhub/models/product_model.dart';
import 'package:burgerhub/services/category_services.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

import 'package:burgerhub/view/admin/services/admin_services.dart';

part 'product_event.dart';
part 'product_state.dart';

class ProductBloc extends Bloc<ProductEvent, ProductState> {
  CategoryServices categoryServices;
  StreamSubscription? productStreamSubscription;

  AdminServices? adminServices;
  ProductBloc(
    this.categoryServices,
  ) : super(ProductInitial()) {
    

    on<getProductsEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(ProductLoading());
      final List<ProductModel> products = [];

      productStreamSubscription =
          categoryServices.getProductsFromDatabase().listen((snapshot) {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((snap) {
          ProductModel product = ProductModel.fromJson(snap.data());
          products.add(product);
        });
        emit(
          ProductLoaded(products: products),
        );
      });

      print(products);
    });
  }
  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    productStreamSubscription!.cancel();

    // TODO: implement close
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

**ProductState.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
part of 'product_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class ProductState extends Equatable {}

class ProductInitial extends ProductState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class ProductUploading extends ProductState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class ProductUploaded extends ProductState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class ProductLoading extends ProductState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class ProductLoaded extends ProductState {
  final List<ProductModel> products;
  ProductLoaded({
    required this.products,
  });
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [products];
}
```

**ProductEvent.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
part of 'product_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class ProductEvent {}



class getProductsEvent extends ProductEvent {}
```

**getProducts Service**

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getProductsFromDatabase() {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot =
        firestore.collection('products').snapshots();
    return snapshot;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error may occur if the number of incoming data in your state management is less than 4! You are calling only 4 items. Try to replace the following code with the itemCount line:

`itemCount: state.products.length,`

if you only need 4 date you should check this case:

`itemCount: state.products.length < 4 : state.products.length : 4,`

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately, it is also not working brother. I am receiving the null list from my bloc when the app is loaded. I can't figure it out why. When I am hot reloading the app it is showing all products without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking only loaded case, You are ignoring the time it takes for the data to arrive. try to check loading state:

```
   BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is ProductLoaded) {
            return Container(
              height: screenSize.height * .31,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                primary: false,
                itemCount: 4,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final List<ProductModel> products = state.products;
                  return productCard(product: products[index]);
                },
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      );
```

Comment: Already tried doing that. I have provided the circular progress indicator for the product loading state but still the same error.

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the `.listen()` method, I anticipate that you get updates when database events occur. If you'd include the code for the `getProductsFromDatabase()` method it could be a bit clearer for us.

If you want to have the `ListView` to update when e.g. posts are made, or other changes occur, then you'd have to yield/emit updated states inside the listen callback where you add the products to the list. Meaning, you can simply try to `emit(ProductLoaded(products: products));` inside the listen callback. I suspect that you will need to merge your current states products with what you get in the listen callback. But that is entirely up to what your service returns to you...

If you as now, only emit the Loaded state once after you have awaited the `listen` method, then it will most likely always be empty. The await for a listener will go really fast, so the callback that add stuff to the products list will probably not have been run. This is probably why a hot reload show your products.

And for the bloc to be able to compare two states with lists of `ProductModel`, that class needs to be comparable. Otherwise the BlocBuilder won't recognize that there is a new state that differs from the previous, and updates will not be seen.

Furthermore, what @Rustam Usmanov wrote in his post about the `itemCount` is also worth taking into consideration. You could otherwise have unwated side effects.

Comment: It is showing the null list when the app is loaded but when I am doing a hot reload than it is updating the UI with products. Also, I have tried the itemcount method. It is still showing the same error. I have updated the code above with my getProducts service. Can you please check it once?

Comment: Is it `null` or is it empty (meaning 0 items) ? Your heading implies zero.

Comment: it is an empty list. But it is updating just after the hot reload and showing all the products perfectly.

Comment: Okey, so do not call it `null`. Because that ìs not the same, and that would not make sense with your current code.

Comment: Read the third part in my post. That is the reason why you have zero first time, and hot reload makes it work. You have to change your itemCount to this `itemCount: state.products.length < 4 : state.products.length : 4,` or this `itemCount: state.products.length,` as Rustam wrote AND you have to emit in the listen callback method.

Comment: Okay. Let me check this once.

Comment: Tried this but showing me another error....
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:bloc/src/emitter.dart': Failed assertion: line 114 pos 7: '!_isCompleted':
package:bloc/src/emitter.dart:114
emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers
and use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246385/discussion-between-robert-sandberg-and-pratul-pant).